# Linux: How to know which process(s) are accessing my files?

Tags: linux, process

I have a mounted partition, which I tried `umounting` and it's giving me an error.  There is a chance that some process is accessing some files in that mounted partition.

How do I know, which process is accessing it, and which files?

Or better, another way to ask this question: How to know all the processes that are accessing a resource? Such as a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `lsof /partitionname` where "partitionname" is the name of the partition you're trying to unmount.

You can also use the `fuser` command for your more general question.

Answer (score 3):

The tool you need is "lsof" (list open files) using this without any options shows you a list of all open resources including files, sockets and so on.

Comment: So you mean, going into the mounted partition and executing "lsof" works as a process explorer. Thanks. Is there any way to do the same on a single file?

Comment: it is not relevant where you exec it. it shows you all ressources that are open. if you want to filter out a specific one you can use lsof | grep whatever

Comment: Seems like `fuser` suggested above helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ fuser -m /mnt/point
```

or

```
$ lsof | grep mount_point|grep -vi grep |grep -vi lsof
```